# What data type is data received from a UDP server in python

Tags: python

So, if I have a server set up like this:

```
class Server():
    def __init__(self, portNum):
        self.sock = None
        self.setup(portNum)


    def setup(self, portNum):
        # Create a UDP socket
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

        # Bind the socket to the port
        server_address = ('localhost', portNum)
        print >> sys.stderr, 'starting up on %s port %s' % server_address
        self.sock.bind(server_address)


    def run(self):
        while True:
            print >>sys.stderr, '\nwaiting to receive message'
            request, address = self.sock.recvfrom(4096)

            print >>sys.stderr, 'received %s bytes from %s' % (len(request),    address)
            print >>sys.stderr, request
```

What is the data type of request? If I were to receive a packet, what would i get if I said print request[1]. Would that be a whole byte, or just one character of a byte string?

Comment: You seem to have the indentation wrong; `setup` and `run` should both be indented one more level.

Comment: Copy and paste error.

Comment: So like if I needed to access just the first two bytes of the packet and see if it was equal to say 0x1234, how would I do that?